# Adding Dropbox to the run dialog

Tags: windows, windows-8, dropbox, run-dialog

You can easily access many user folders using the `Run` command (<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>), including `documents`, `downloads`, `pictures`.

[image]

How can I add Dropbox support for this? That is, how can I press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type "dropbox" and have the Dropbox folder appear?

Answer (score 1):

Opening a directory, a file, or an application using the `Run` command (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) requires the following environment variables to work:

-PATH
-PATHEXT

To view, edit or remove environment variables, use theses steps:
1) Right click on the Computer icon on your Desktop (or Start Menu) and choose "Properties" (Alternatively, use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>)

2) The System window appears, click on "Advanced system settings" in the left pane.

3) In the System Properties window select the "Advanced" tab and click on "Environment Variables"

Here you can view or modify the PATH and PATHEXT variables listed under System variables.

When using the `Run` command, Windows uses the directories listed in PATH.
All file extensions in PATHEXT can be omitted, so add ".LNK" to PATHEXT.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to place a shortcut to your Dropbox folder in your `C:\Windows` folder.

I ran into an issue on Windows 8 directly creating a shortcut in the `C:\Windows` folder, so I had to first create the shortcut to my Dropbox directory (`F:\Dropbox`) on my Desktop, then move the shortcut to my Windows directory.

Now, when I press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> I can type "dropbox" and my Dropbox window will appear.